# java.io API : list method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, io

I am using  java.io API's. There are lots of file in my dir for the below pattern.

```
    FilenameFilter fileFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

            return name.matches(filePrefix+"_.*\\."+fileExt);

        }
    };

    String listFiles [] = dirFile.list(fileFilter);
       for(int i = 0 ;i < listFiles.length ; i++){
        listOfFiles.add(listFiles[i]);
        // need only 10 files to processed
        if(i == 10){
            break;
        }
    }
```

I wanted to know that `list` method will get listing based on what.I am if i wanted to have time based sorting, for example - if i want 10 files which are oldest /or latest.

How will i do it.

Solution :

```
Arrays.sort(listFiles, new Comparator<File>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above only *filters*. You may be better off using the `File.listFiles()` method, which returns a set of `File` objects (you can provide an optional filter, as above). These objects will have the attributes that you want to further sort on (perhaps writing a custom `Comparator`?). See [the doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) and a sorting tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).

Comment: Can you please give me a idea about how to use comparator in this case.

Comment: One more question : How listFile gives the result.It return set of file objects based on alphabetical order, timestamp or what ? I means ls -ltr, ls or just a random output

Comment: listFiles() doesn't order by default. See the doc. Linked above. You'll need to write your own comparator. Again, I've linked some doc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use`'listFiles(fileFilter)'` to list File Objects instead of strings and then `sort/filter` them